# Warning: Hauck-Donner effect detected in the following estimate(s): INTERCEPT

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, intercept, separation

This is a quick question because I could not find an answer online.

I ran a truncated Poisson model and I got the warning in the title (perfect separation?) affecting my intercept.

The output is:

```r
Call:
vglm(formula = private_sensors ~ lag_private_sensors + gov_monitors + 
    density + avg_income + avg_age + log2_sex_ratio + years_edu + 
    PM10 + offset(log(k_people)), family = pospoisson(), 
    data = filter(df_2019_north, private_sensors > 0))

Coefficients: 
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -2.640e+01  4.657e+00  -5.670 1.43e-08 ***
lag_private_sensors  5.962e-02  7.048e-02   0.846   0.3976    
gov_monitors        -1.873e-01  1.129e-01  -1.660   0.0970 .  
density             -5.445e-01  7.803e-02  -6.978 2.99e-12 ***
avg_income           1.549e-01  6.375e-02   2.429   0.0151 *  
avg_age              8.810e-02  9.207e-02   0.957   0.3386    
log2_sex_ratio      -6.435e+00  3.111e+00  -2.068   0.0386 *  
years_edu            1.591e+00  2.690e-01   5.916 3.30e-09 ***
PM10                -4.209e-04  7.559e-04  -0.557   0.5777    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Name of linear predictor: loglink(lambda) 

Log-likelihood: -152.373 on 92 degrees of freedom

Number of Fisher scoring iterations: 7 

Warning: Hauck-Donner effect detected in the following estimate(s):
'(Intercept)'
```

Question 1: does this error affect only my intercept or do I have to toss my whole model?

Question 2: the coefficient and SE on `density` seem suspicious as well, any idea of why I don't get the warning there?

Any help is very appreciated!
A description of what I am doing, in case you need more background, is here:  [Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637932/percentage-of-females-as-a-regressor-in-count-model-with-population-as-offset/)

Comment: You use `vglm` package, its author have a paper here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.08431.pdf  about Hauck-Donner effect, I will have a look! But, in your case, the peoblem is signalled with the intercept, might not be serious, maybe formulate your hypothesis and do a likelihood ratio test, do not depend on the Wald tests from the output?

Comment: Have you tried centering (and maybe scaling) all the continuous predictors, as suggested in your related question? This might just represent a numerical precision problem. On the other hand, the extremely small p-values for all of `(Intercept)`, `density` and `years_edu` might mean that some particular combinations of `density` and `years_edu`  lead to something close to perfect predictions.